# Parsing an html table with pd.read_html where cells contain full-tables themselves

Tags: python, html, pandas, beautifulsoup, lxml

I need to parse a table from html that has other tables nested within the larger table. As called below with `pd.read_html`, each of these nested tables are parsed and then "inserted"/"concatenated" as rows.

I'd like these nested tables to each be parsed into their own `pd.DataFrames` and the inserted as objects as the value of the corresponding column.

If this is *not* possible, having raw html for the nested table as a string in the corresponding position would be fine.

Code as tested:

```py
import pandas as pd
df_up = pd.read_html("up_pf00344.test.html", attrs = {'id': 'results'})
```

Screenshot of output:
[image: Screenshot of table as parsed]

Screenshot of table as rendered in html:
[image: Screenshot of table as html]

Link to file: https://gist.github.com/smsaladi/6adb30efbe70f9fed0306b226e8ad0d8#file-up_pf00344-test-html-L62

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use [`read_html`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.read_html.html) to read nested tables, but you can roll your own html reader and use `read_html` for table cells:

```
import pandas as pd
import bs4

with open('up_pf00344.test.html') as f:
    html = f.read()
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
results = soup.find(attrs = {'id': 'results'})

# get first visible header row as dataframe headers
for row in results.thead.find_all('tr'):
    if 'display:none' not in row.get('style',''):
        df = pd.DataFrame(columns=[col.get_text() for col in row.find_all('th')])
    break

# append all table rows to dataframe
for row in results.tbody.find_all('tr', recursive=False):
    if 'display:none' in row.get('style',''):
        continue
    df_row = []
    for col in row.find_all('td', recursive=False):
        table = col.find_all('table')
        df_row.append(pd.read_html(str(col))[0] if table else col.get_text())
    df.loc[len(df)] = df_row
```

Result of `df.iloc[0].map(type)`:

```
                                                            <class 'str'>
Entry                                                       <class 'str'>
Organism                                                    <class 'str'>
Protein names                                               <class 'str'>
Gene names                                                  <class 'str'>
Length                                                      <class 'str'>
Cross-reference (Pfam)                                      <class 'str'>
Cross-reference (InterPro)                                  <class 'str'>
Taxonomic lineage IDs                                       <class 'str'>
Subcellular location [CC]                                   <class 'str'>
Signal peptide                                              <class 'str'>
Transit peptide                                             <class 'str'>
Topological domain                  <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Transmembrane                       <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Intramembrane                       <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Sequence caution                                            <class 'str'>
Caution                                                     <class 'str'>
Taxonomic lineage (SUPERKINGDOM)                            <class 'str'>
Taxonomic lineage (KINGDOM)                                 <class 'str'>
Taxonomic lineage (PHYLUM)                                  <class 'str'>
Cross-reference (RefSeq)                                    <class 'str'>
Cross-reference (EMBL)                                      <class 'str'>
e                                                           <class 'str'>
```

Bonus: As your table rows have an `id`, you could use it as index of your dataframe `df.loc[row.get('id')] = df_row` instead of `df.loc[len(df)] = df_row`.