# How to scrape a table that has a nested table?

Tags: python, pandas, selenium, beautifulsoup, html-table

I am trying to scrape the table that is shown in the attached image.

[image: the table I want to scrape]

The desired output:

[image: the desired output in excel]

I tried scraping it using selenium and beautiful soup library of python. but the excel output is all messed up especially the nested table part. I want the output as shown in the image above.
Here is the HTML code for this table.

```
<table class="table collapse show" id="HTBXactiveShelfReg">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">File Number</th>
      <th scope="col">Date of Effect</th>
      <th scope="col">Date of Expiration</th>
      <th scope="col">I.B.6 Restricted</th>
      <th scope="col">Offering Value</th>
      <th scope="col">Offering Value Breakdown</th>
      <th scope="col">Offering Type</th>
      <th scope="col">Warrant Exercise Prices</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

    
    <tr>
      <td>
        <a href="https://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/browse-edgar?action=getcompany&amp;filenum=333-237808&amp;owner=exclude&amp;count=100" target="_blank" style="color: #3380FF">333-237808</a>
      </td>
      <td>05/04/2020</td>
      <td>04/23/2023</td>
      <td>No</td>
      <td>$150,000,000.00</td>
      <td>
        
        <table class="table" id="primary_breakdown_424">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th scope="col">Source</th>
              <th scope="col">Date</th>
              <th scope="col">Value Used</th>
              <th scope="col">Value Remaining</th>
              <th scope="col">Underwriter</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
          
            <tr>
              <td><a href="https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1476963/000155335020000657/htbx_424b.htm" target="_blank" style="color: #3380FF">424B5</a></td>
              <td>07/27/2020</td>
              <td>$100,000,000.00</td>
              <td>$50,000,000.00</td>
              <td>B.&nbsp;Riley</td>
            </tr>
          
          </tbody>
        </table>
        
      </td>
      <td>AtTheMarket</td>
      <td>
        
        None
        
      </td>
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
      <td>
        <a href="https://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/browse-edgar?action=getcompany&amp;filenum=333-221201&amp;owner=exclude&amp;count=100" target="_blank" style="color: #3380FF">333-221201</a>
      </td>
      <td>11/13/2017</td>
      <td>10/30/2020</td>
      <td>Yes</td>
      <td>$50,000,000.00</td>
      <td>
        
        <table class="table" id="primary_breakdown_424">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th scope="col">Source</th>
              <th scope="col">Date</th>
              <th scope="col">Value Used</th>
              <th scope="col">Value Remaining</th>
              <th scope="col">Underwriter</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
          
            <tr>
              <td><a href="https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1476963/000155335018000058/htbx_424b5.htm" target="_blank" style="color: #3380FF">424B5</a></td>
              <td>01/19/2018</td>
              <td>$3,658,000.00</td>
              <td>$46,342,000.00</td>
              <td>H.C. Wainwright</td>
            </tr>
          
            <tr>
              <td><a href="https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1476963/000155335018000223/htbx_424b5.htm" target="_blank" style="color: #3380FF">424B5</a></td>
              <td>03/16/2018</td>
              <td>$1,300,000.00</td>
              <td>$45,042,000.00</td>
              <td>H.C. Wainwright</td>
            </tr>
          
            <tr>
              <td><a href="https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1476963/000155335018001287/htbx_424b.htm" target="_blank" style="color: #3380FF">424B2</a></td>
              <td>11/21/2018</td>
              <td>$12,000,000.00</td>
              <td>$33,042,000.00</td>
              <td>A.G.P.</td>
            </tr>
          
            <tr>
              <td><a href="https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1476963/000155335019000327/htbx_424b.htm" target="_blank" style="color: #3380FF">424B5</a></td>
              <td>04/04/2019</td>
              <td>$18,000,000.00</td>
              <td>$15,042,000.00</td>
              <td>B. Riley</td>
            </tr>
          
          </tbody>
        </table>
        
      </td>
      <td>AtTheMarket</td>
      <td>
        
        <table class="table" id="primarywarrants">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th scope="col">Source</th>
              <th scope="col">Date</th>
              <th scope="col">Price</th>
              <th scope="col"># Warrants Offered</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
          
            <tr>
              <td><a href="https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1476963/000155335019000327/htbx_424b.htm" target="_blank" style="color: #3380FF">424B5</a></td>
              <td>04/04/2019</td>
              <td>$0.48</td>
              <td>32,610</td>
            </tr>
          
            <tr>
              <td><a href="https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1476963/000155335019000327/htbx_424b.htm" target="_blank" style="color: #3380FF">424B5</a></td>
              <td>04/04/2019</td>
              <td>$1.00</td>
              <td>6,825,000</td>
            </tr>
          
          </tbody>
        </table>
        
      </td>
    </tr>
    

  </tbody>
</table>
```

The code I've tried:

```
output = []

table = driver.find_element_by_id('HTBXactiveShelfReg')
output.append([i.text for i in table.find_elements_by_tag_name('th')])
rows = table.find_elements_by_tag_name('tr')
for row in rows:
    output.append(['{}'.format(x.text) for x in row.find_elements_by_tag_name('td')])
file = os.path.join('htb.csv')
outfile = open(file, "a")
for row in output:
    outfile.write('"' + '","'.join(row) + '"\n')
outfile.close()
```

Comment: would mind sharing the code you have tried so far?

Comment: @PrakharJhudele I've shared it. please check.

Comment: Next time you ask question, you'd better contain some specific language tags, so more people could help you.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using Pandas for scraping tables (or any other DataFrame like content) from the web. This has been solved in Pandas dev page. You might want to take a [look](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/28851)

And here is the link to the Duplicate [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58280302/parsing-an-html-table-with-pd-read-html-where-cells-contain-full-tables-themselv/58284784#58284784)..

Cheers!

Comment: I still can't get the desired output in excel as shown in the image attached in the above post.

Comment: Can you please share the link to the table? I can give it a try. I would guess there are two ways froward. One would be to use Pandas multi index which will result in a fairly complicated table structure. Other is to flatten the table. That is get rid of "Offering Value Breakdown" and make sub columns into fully independent column.